# EF6 - Removing then Adding

Tags: entity-framework

> Conflicting changes detected. This may happen when trying to insert multiple entities with the same key.

I am getting the error above with the code below:

```
var curUserLanguages = Context.UserLanguages.Where(ul => ul.UserDataId == userDataId).ToList();
Context.UserLanguages.RemoveRange(curUserLanguages);

foreach (var langId in languageIds)
{
    ...
    Context.UserLanguages.Add(newUL); 
}

Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Actually, it might be helpful to see what you're trying to add. Does `UserLanguage` have an related entities that are also being inserted? Those might be causing the error as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `UserLanguage` entities with the same key as entities in `curUserLanguages`. Even though you intend to remove those entities with `RemoveRange`, the context is still tracking them since you haven't saved changes yet, and the context is unable to track multiple entities of the same type that use the same key.

It might make sense for you to find which entities are being replaced and updating their properties before removing the entities that aren't being replaced.

Comment: I don't understand. Should I call SaveChanges after the RemoveRange?